# What can be used to spawn a completely seperate process in Bourne Shell (Or csh)

Tags: process, csh, sh

I'm testing out a way to run a process separate from the original process in sh.
I've already asked and heard that & is used for spawning a child process.
By calling a program, in this case glxgears, because it has a lot of STDOUT (so I can test where output goes), using backticks.

```
glxgears&
```

does not keep output out of the current shell where

```
`glxgears`&
```

causes

```
comp:~ user$ `glxgears`&
[1] 14511
comp:~ user$ X connection to /tmp/launch-dZalNv/org.x:0 broken (explicit kill or server shutdown).

[1]+  Exit 1                  `glxgears`
comp:~ user$
```

I accept that **`[1] 14511`** is just notification of proper process launch, but how is the X Server still **able** to dump output in my shell?
And why if I have launched a separate process is

```
[1]+  Exit 1                  `glxgears`
```

Showing up? The shell never warns me of other closing processes!

I think I've deduced that it may have to do with the process group which remains the PID of my shell even after my shell is closed. All other processes have their own process group.
Even using

```
`glxgears&`&
```

retains the original shell's PID as the process group!

I want to be able to run a program (in this case glxgears) without any association to the launching shell, no output of any kind.

If you could also explain why the X server can send my starting process the output that be very much appreciated.

Comment: As an aside, that is not what you use backticks for.  Once the process produces some output, the shell will attempt to use the first word of output as a command name to execute. Behold: `\`echo moo\`` -> sh: moo: command not found

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
nohup glxgears >/dev/null 2>&1 &
```

- `2>&1` makes the program's stderr to be stdout.
- `>/dev/null` makes stdout to be /dev/null, so that you will see nothing on your terminal, and the program will not receive a boken pipe signal if you close your terminal
- With `nohup`, the program will not terminate if its parent is terminated

Comment: Put the whole thing in parentheses if you want the process to be completely independent (a child of the `init` process) rather than a child of your shell process.  `( nohup glxgears >/dev/null 2>&1 &
 )`

Comment: But why is STDERR/STDOUT and  still dumped to parent process shell (so far as I can tell). Can you launch it without dumping its output to my shell? Why is it outputting on the launching shell?

Comment: stdout is where the program writes its normal output, usually it's your shell. stderr is where it outputs errors, it's your shell too. In ` `glxgears` ` you are capturing only the normal output, not errors.

Comment: and backtics=command substitution, for which the desired results is to  'present' the stdout back to the parent shell, usually for assignment to a variable (and other uses). Put another way, enclosing your cmd in backtics, or better yet $( ...) , is working as designed. Instead of /dev/null as above, consider substituting a full path to a log/trace file, i.e. /tmp/mySystem/glxgears.$(/bin/date +%Y%m%d.%H%M).trace_log. Good luck.

Comment: @arnaud576875: stdout and stderr are not normally "the shell", they're normally the same as the shell process's own stdout and stderr.  But in this case, the `>/dev/null 2>&1` should redirect the stdout and stdout of the `glxgears` command to `/dev/null`, i.e., it should discard them.

Comment: But how does it send them to my shell after It becomes a child of init? Isn't the whole point of closing the parent process to seperate it from the original parent?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be confusing process association with I/O streams. The only thing special about background processes is that they return interactive control to the calling shell, nothing more. They still use the same stdout and stderr streams of the same terminal. Where else would they write output to? The only semi-reasonable things to do would be (a) to discard output completely (b) to point them to some new file. Both were considered too unlikely to be useful to be the default behavior, so the default is still to use the terminal of the calling process for output. You can override this choice with the `>` operator, as arnaud has shown.

Comment: But why after becoming a child of **init** does the process still send STDERR to the process group not parent process init?

Comment: Because very likely, init has no terminal attached, so the output would simply vanish into nothingness. It's better to route the output to the parent's terminal: if you get it and don't like it, you can suppress it, but if you don't get it and would like it, you're out of luck.